# Python: Activate last slide in active PowerPoint presentation

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to add a slide to an active PowerPoint presentation, and activate it (make it visible) at the same time.

Using Python, the snippet below will add a slide to an active PowerPoint presentation. I'm using that together with functions like `Base.Shapes.AddPicture` to add pictures that I've produced with matplotlib, but I'm leaving that part out here.

**Run this once:**

```
import win32com.client
Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
Presentation = Application.Activepresentation
slidenr = Presentation.Slides.Count + 1
Base = Presentation.Slides.Add(slidenr, 12)
```

**And you'll get this:**

[image]

So far so good. But run it a bunch of times, and you'll end up with the situation described in the picture below. Notice that you'll have to use the scrollbar to see the last produced slide.

[image]

This messes with my work-flow, since I'd like to produce a chart, send it to PowerPoint, make a few adjusments, send a new version to PowerPoint and inspect it without having to switch from my python IDE to PowerPoint.

I thought this would be the easiest thing in the world to accomplish, but I've found nothing on SO, in the [docs](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or elsewhere. Maybe my googling abilities are just horrible...

Anyway, thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `Presentation.slides(slidenr).select()` after  `Presentation.Slides.Add(slidenr, 12)`

OR

Try modifying `Presentation.Slides.Add(slidenr, 12)` to `Presentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)`

Comment: This doesn't add a slide at the end and activates it. It adds a new slide at the beginning of the presentation. But at least it keeps the new slide in focus, which really was the main objective, so thanks alot! Any idea how to activate the last slide thogh?

Comment: @vestland `Presentation.slides(slidenr).select()` will do that